# Why does MiniDLNA stop indexing files?

Tags: dlna

---

I've read the useful question [why is the minidlna database not refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180409/why-is-the-minidlna-database-not-being-refreshed) and [minidlna - not indexing files](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10531/minidlna-issue-not-indexing-files) but this problem is different: It seems to stop scanning files at a certain file/after a certain directory.

Set up:

- Running on Raspberry PI
- Minidlna v1.2.1 from Raspbian Buster
- Large music collection (although it only gets up to a few hundred files), a mix of formats.
- `fs.inotify.maxuserwatches=65536` in `sysctl.conf`
- User `minidlna` has read access to full media library
- `/var/cache/minidlna` where it keeps its database files, is on an ext4 partition.
- Logging is set to:

  ```
  log_level=debug,artwork=debug,database=debug,inotify=debug,scanner=debug,metadata=debug,http=warn,ssdp=debug,tivo=warn
  ```
- Watching `top`, the system does not seem to run out of memory while scanning.
- The only error in the log is:

  > [2019/11/14 20:07:35] tagutils/tagutils-mp3.c:695: info: Bad header... dropping back for full frame search [/drive/files/Music/00 Various/some-song.mp3]

  But the scan appears to continue after this.

The problem lines seem to be here:

```
[2019/11/14 20:07:35] scanner.c:730: info: Scanning /drive/files/Music/00 Various/SomeFolder
[2019/11/14 20:07:37] monitor.c:178: debug: Add watch to /drive/files/Music
```

where it looks like it stops scanning and starts adding watches; there's no errors or warnings.

Stumped!

Answer (score 0):

I had to run
`sudo minidlnad -d -R`
to find I had a file with an invalid JPEG in it. Luckily, I could just delete the file. If that's not an option for you, there may be some way of editing the metadata for whatever file you have a problem with.

Comment: thanks, but I've tried deleting the databse and rescanning, it always gets stuck somewhere - but the problem is it doesn't tell me where it got stuck, and with 18k files it's a bit of a needle in a haystack!

Comment: That's why running it in the terminal, as opposed to as a service, helps. The last file mentioned when it stops is the one to look at.